# Why does T-SQL think a an item is a column name?

Tags: t-sql, dataexplorer

Note: I am just starting with SQL/T-SQL and I am not searching for a more elegant solution, just for a fix.

So I'm trying to use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to count how many times a badge has been awarded. My query goes something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id)
FROM Badges
WHERE Name = "Scholar"
```

The results should be the number of times the Badge has been awarded. It, however, returns this error:

```
Line 3: Invalid column name 'Scholar'.
```

Comment: Because you put it in double quotes, the ANSI-SQL delimit identifier for **object** names. Single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings.

Comment: *"The results should be (at least according to what I have read online)"* **If** what you read *did* say that, it's wrong. I would look at other articles.

Comment: @Larnu I'm so sorry for mentioning that, I have never seen a language distinguish between a single quote and a double quote.

Comment: Plenty do, gurkensaas. For example, in bash you can't interpolate in single quotes.

Comment: @gurkensaas Ref: T-SQL [delimited identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#classes-of-identifiers) and [character string constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#character-string-constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace double quote to single quote

```
SELECT COUNT(Id)
FROM Badges
WHERE Name = 'Scholar'
```